# HTML DOM remove/replace between <tr> and </tr> tags

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I've searched for solution but i'm lost. I have to remove or replace with blank everything between `<tr>` tags. I'm loading html file, which contains many `<tr>` tags, my goal is to remove `<tr>` with specific id. My `<tr>` looks like this:

```
<tr id="ctl00_cphMain_DisplayRecords1_RepeaterResults_ctl03_trZSD">
    <td id="ctl00_cphMain_DisplayRecords1_RepeaterResults_ctl03_tdZSD" class="td-zsd footable-visible footable-last-column footable-first-column" colspan="9">
         <div id="divZSDBanners" class="table-banners-zsd clearfix">
              <div>
                  <div class="medium-4 columns zsd-ext-ad">
                     <div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        </script>
                        <script>
                        </script>
                        <div id="ctl00_cphMain_DisplayRecords1_RepeaterResults_ctl03_ctl00_divSpace1" class="adSpacer">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                  </script>
              </div>
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm using Simple HTML DOM, I've already tried with `$html->find('tr[id=tr_id])`, but don't know to replace everything between, including divs and script tags.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `->innertext` property:

```
$tr = $html->find( 'tr[id=tr_id]', 0 );  // Select first node (0)
$tr->innertext = '';
echo $html->save();
```

Output:

```
<tr id="tr_id"></tr>
```

Or:

```
$tr->innertext = '<td>New Content</td>';
echo $html->save();
```

Output:

```
<tr id="tr_id"><td>New Content</td></tr>
```

Comment: Tried but no success with ->innertext

Comment: Add real HTML to your question. Code in my answer is tested as working (also on your HTML sample).

Comment: I added actual HTML code. Sory for long ids and classes.

Comment: It works also with new HTML. Where's this HTML come from? Did you copy it from browser?

Comment: Yes, it's parsed from website. I just noticed in browser is working well, but if I open file in notepad, nothing changed.

Comment: I suspect that there is not this `<tr>` in page source and that it is created by javascript. Can you update question adding part of code that retrieve html with real URL?

Comment: Actually, I load HTML from file, not directly from website. This tr is an advertisement and it hindering further progress... has to be removed

Comment: If you want, you can share your file and I can test it. (in about 1 hour... now I have to go... )

Comment: Sorry... i set $html->save() instead of $html->save('file.html'); problem solved :) thanks for labor ;)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `TR` element itself via [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), use the `removeChild` method of its parent node:

```
$tr->parentNode->removeChild($tr);
```

To remove the element’s *contents*, either set its `textContent` property to empty string `''` (PHP 5.6.1+) or remove all child nodes one by one using the element’s `removeChild()` method in a loop, e. g.:

```
while ($tr->lastChild) {
    $tr->removeChild($tr->lastChild);
}
```

`SimpleXMLElement` object can be converted to `DOMElement` object using the [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) function.

Comment: Any spec compliant parser won't insert any element child into a `tr` element except for `td` and `th` elements; everything else will be foster parented to before the `table` element. So `html5lib-php` won't put any `div` there.

Comment: @gsnedders Fwiw, your comment is probably not relevant anymore.